# Dice game rules implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, dice

My in-laws taught me a dice game a couple years ago, and we play every once in a while. [A recent excellent answer from @radarbob](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33151/23788) inspired me to proceed with translating the rules of that dice game into code.

Here's what came out of it:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So it works perfectly, and somehow I'm just as unlucky with this virtual version as in the real-life one (had to click dozens of time to get a freakin' *opening roll*; by that time my mother-in-law already has thousands of points, every time). At least in this version I can inject some `CrookedDie` implementation if I want!

I'd like the `CalculateRollScore` method reviewed, to see what could be improved.

It turns out I *thought* the code was working as it should. So I wrote a couple unit tests and... well this is where *not writing unit tests* has bitten me.

Well I had to change the rules anyway, since the rule for 4x 1's was just my wife being mixed-up. My mother-in-law and I agree that 3x 1's is 1000, 4x 1's is 2000 and 5x 1's is 3000.

So before I show any code, I'll show this:

[image: passing tests]

Now here's the *working* code ([view original code here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/33363/2)), with only minor changes that don't mootinize any already posted answer:

```
namespace DiceGame
{
    public interface IRollScoreRules
    {
        int CalculateRollScore(IEnumerable<IRollResult<int>> results);
    }

    public class GameRollScoreRules : IRollScoreRules
    {
        public virtual bool IsOpeningRoll(IEnumerable<IRollResult<int>> results)
        {
            return CalculateRollScore(results) >= 500;
        }

        public virtual int CalculateRollScore(IEnumerable<IRollResult<int>> results)
        {
            var score = 0;

            // if less than 3 1's were rolled, each rolled 1 is 100pts:
            score += results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
                            .Where(g => g.Key == 1)
                            .Where(g => g.Count() < 3)
                            .Sum(g => g.Count() * 100);

            // if less than 3 5's were rolled, each rolled 5 is 50pts:
            score += results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
                            .Where(g => g.Key == 5)
                            .Where(g => g.Count() < 3)
                            .Sum(g => g.Count() * 50);

            // if more than 3 of anything other than 1 were rolled, determine number of "extra dice":
            var extras = results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
                                .Where(g => g.Key != 1 && g.Count() > 3)
                                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Count() - 3);

            var extraOnes = results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
                                   .Where(g => g.Key == 1 && g.Count() > 3)
                                   .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Count() - 3);

            // any triplet is 100x nominal value; each extra die is another 100x nominal value:
            score += results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
                            .Where(g => (g.Key != 1 && g.Count() >= 3))
                            .Sum(g => (g.Key * 100) + (extras.ContainsKey(g.Key) ? extras[g.Key] : 0) * (g.Key * 100));

            //score += results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
            //    .Where(g => (g.Key == 1 && g.Count() >= 3))
            //    .Sum(g => (g.Key * 100) + (extraOnes.ContainsKey(g.Key) ? extraOnes[g.Key] : 0) * (g.Key * 100));

            // 3x 1's is 1000x nominal value; each extra die is another 1000x nominal value:
            score += results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
                            .Where(g => g.Key == 1 && g.Count() >= 3)
                            .Sum(g => (g.Key * 1000) + (extraOnes.ContainsKey(g.Key) ? extraOnes[g.Key] : 0) * (g.Key * 1000));

            return score;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I am not familiar with die, but the obvious improvement is to encapsulate those rules into separate entities. For example:

```
public interface IRollScoreRule
{
    int CalculateRollScore(IEnumerable<IRollResult<int>> results);
}

public interface IRollScoreRules : IRollScoreRule
{
    bool IsOpeningRoll(IEnumerable<IRollResult<int>> results);
    void AddRule(IRollScoreRule rule);
    void RemoveRule(IRollScoreRule rule);
}

public class ScoreFivesRule : IRollScoreRule
{
    int CalculateRollScore(IEnumerable<IRollResult<int>> results)
    {
        // i think some of this logic can be extracted to base class
        // results.GroupBy(e => e.Value).Where(g => g.Key == 5) part for example
        // is common for most of the rules
        var score = results.GroupBy(e => e.Value)
                        .Where(g => g.Key == 5)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() < 3)
                        .Sum(g => g.Count() * 50);
        return score;
    }
}
```

Then in your `GameRollScoreRules.CalculateRollScore` method you can iterate through collection of rules (using `IEnumerable.Aggregate`, for example) to get the total score, instead of having one huge method.

I also think you might want to tweak the `IsOpeningRoll` method. I mean, if I understand the use-case from your screenshots correctly, then with every dice roll, you want to know both - score value and if this value is higher then `500`. Which means that using your `GameRollScoreRules` class as it is you would essentially calculate score twice (by calling `CalculateRollScore` and `IsOpeningRoll` methods). I think you sould either pass the resulting score to `IsOpeningRoll` method as a parameter, or remove this method all together and replace `CalculateRollScore` return type with some complex object (which will contain score value and bool flag) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Frankly speaking, if someone in my team wrote those LINQ statements, I would kill him. Using LINQ on this, you just complicated the simple task. I tried to reconstruct it using simple C#, but yet I am still not sure if it's correct.

```
    public virtual int CalculateRollScore(IEnumerable<IRollResult<int>> results)
    {
        var score = 0;
        var diceMap = (new int[7]).ToList();
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            diceMap[item.Value]++;
        }

        // if less than 4 1's were rolled, each rolled 1 is 100pts:
        if (diceMap[1] < 4)
        {
            score += diceMap[1] * 100;
        }

        // if less than 3 5's were rolled, each rolled 5 is 50pts:
        if (diceMap[5] < 3)
        {
            score += diceMap[5] * 50;
        }

        int nominalValue = diceMap.FindIndex(i => i >= 3);
        int dieCount = nominalValue > 0 ? diceMap[nominalValue] : 0;
        // any triplet is 100x nominal value; each extra die is another 100x nominal value:
        if (nominalValue > 0)
        {
            int extra = dieCount > 3 ? (dieCount - 3) * nominalValue * 100 : 0;
            score += nominalValue * 100 + extra;
        }

        // 4x 1's is 1000x nominal value; each extra die is another 1000x nominal value:
        if (nominalValue == 1 && dieCount >= 4)
        {
            int extra1 = dieCount > 4 ? (dieCount - 4) * nominalValue * 1000 : 0;
            score += nominalValue * 1000 + extra1;
        }
        return score;
    }
```

As I tested my method, the score of the set `{ 4, 1, 1, 1, 1 }` is not matched with your method. Your method returns 1100, but it should be 1200

- 100 for triplet of 1's
- 100 for extra 1
- 1000 for 4x of 1

Correct me if I'm wrong, as I'm not familiar with the rules at all.

Comment: now this is where *not writing unit tests* has bitten me - you're absolutely right, I have undeniable proof right before my eyes (with a nicely failing test) that 4x 1's scores 1100. I'll fix that and edit OP with corrected code (I'll leave the nasty Linq, to not mootinize your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

#### I think you're over-thinking the solution

My first thought is that I'd like to iterate a `Rule` collection, and give each rule the dice roll results.

```
foreach(Rule rule in RulesCollection) {
    score =+ rule.calculate(results);
}
```

With this "wishful thinking" starting point this means all your rules derive, or implement, `Rule` (or whatever you want to call it). If in the final analysis every rule calculates a score for that specific dice combination then the above snippet should be achievable. If a given rule needs unique methods, fine; but for polymorphic purposes they all `calculate` so they can all implement (or inherit) `Rule`.

#### Dump the interfaces

`interface`s implementing `interfaces` implemented by `abstract` classes. This is madness. If all this is coming from *code to interfaces, not implementation* "interface" can be an `abstract` class, `interface`, or even a non-abstract class. The "interface" means giving the client code a consistent set of methods & properties so every object can be handled the same. If there is only one class implementing an `interface`, that interface is likely unnecessary. If in the future you need one, make it then.

#### Encapsulate for Consistency, Clarity, and Expressiveness

There is clearly a need for the grouped dice. My initial thought is that this best fits in the `Dice` class. AND that *data structure* could be a class as well.

```
public class Dice {
    public DiceMap Map { get; private set; }

    public Dice (int diceCount) {
        //existing code

        DiceMap = new DiceMap(sidesCount);
    }

     public int Roll() {
         //did not show all original code.

         int temp;

         foreach (Die die in dice) {  //does this need to be a "for" ?
             temp = die.Roll();
             total =+ temp;
             DiceMap[temp-1]++;
         }
     }

     // calling before rolling returns zero, makes sense.
     public int HowMany(int count) { return groups.HowMany(count); }

     // yes, an inner class. Only Dice class needs it.
     // I'll admit this may be overkill but I want to illustrate the idea
     // of encapsulating - hiding structure (the array) while exposing
     // it's meaning - how many 1's? for example.

     // The other point is to "go deep with OO design", so to speak.

     public class DiceMap {
         int[] groups;

         public DiceMap (int count) { groups = new int[count]; }

         public int HowMany(int dieFace) {
             // check for dieFace out of array bounds

             return groups[dieFace-1];
         }
    }
}
```

now deep in some `Rule` class this:

```
if (myDice.HowMany(3) > 3) { // your code here }
```

or this, depending on what we decide to pass in

```
if (myDiceMap.HowMany(3) > 3 )
```

#### RuleCollection

Make a class and put those "Add" and "Remove" functions in there!

```
public class RuleCollection {
    protected List<Rule> rules;

    public RuleCollection (params Rule[] rules) {
        this.rules = new List<Rule>;
        foreach (Rule rule in Rules) { rules.Add(rule); }

    public void Add (Rule rule) { rules.Add(rule); }
    public bool Remove (Rule rule) { return rules.Remove(rule) }
     // List<T>.Remove() returns a bool.

    // assumes dice have been rolled
    public int Calculate(DiceMap diceMap) {
        int score = 0;

        foreach (Rule rule in rules) {
            score =+ rule.Calculate(diceMap);
        }
    }
}
```

#### OpeningRoleRule

Seems to me every `Rule` implements a piece of the overall score counting for a single roll of the dice. So the opening roll is just all those rules applied - see above - then checked against some minimum value. So maybe it's not a `Rule` per-se.

```
public class TheGameClass {
   protected RulesCollection rules;
   protected Dice dice;

   dice.Roll();
   if ( rules.Calculate(dice.Map) >= minimumOpeningScore ) { ... }
}
```

#### OO Change Goodness

If the number of dice sides does not change, I want to do this:

```
public class DiceMap {
   // new properties
   public int Ones { get { return groups[0]; }
   public int Twos { get { return groups[1]; }
   // and so on
   public int Sixes { get { return groups[5]; }
}
```

**Notice all the dice game code we don't have to touch!**

Comment: +1 I *am* overthinking it! ...but there's more to the game, I was going to post a follow-up question later, maybe over the weekend. You're right the interfaces stem from my understanding of SOLID, I'll see what I'm actually using and what I can dump. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure any rule precedence is accounted for in the `Rule` list ordering.